# How do I eliminate the linker errors in Xcode for Ionic-v1 App?

Tags: linker, cocoapods, xcode10.1, ionic-v1

I updated a plugin in my ionic-v1 app which required me to remove and add the ios platform. After doing that I started getting Linker errors for 3 Pods - errors which were not there before and the Pods were in use.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option ‘-L/Users/stibrewal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cgwzxyqdyechhzaljutviiyalhso/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac’

ld: warning: directory not found for option ‘-L/Users/stibrewal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cgwzxyqdyechhzaljutviiyalhso/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf’

ld: warning: directory not found for option ‘-L/Users/stibrewal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cgwzxyqdyechhzaljutviiyalhso/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/nanopb’

ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
```

I have tried Pod installs again. I have checked that the Pods are actually there in the Pods directory.

It seems like missing something silly/obvious but doesn't know what to do to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by updating version of cocoapods gem to 1.6.1